# How to render particle hairs in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I have created a hairstyle with the hair particle system. I can't render the exact style in final render, but I can render that in openGL.
[image: three views of the hair]

[image]

Comment: Could you upload a .blend file to a service like [**Blend-Exchange**](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the link in your question? It would helps us a lot, many critical options are minimized so we can't check their values.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=196" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/196/) Here , i have attached the blend file, please have a look.

Comment: Paste that in the question instead please . . .

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for my question.

Increase steps value to above 6 or 8 in particle render tab.[image]

Comment: To get all details of hair style, steps value should be high.

Answer (score 0):

Cycles animation engine doesn't show particles in render. Unlike in blender engine were a particle shows up as a signal pixel. The best way to fix your problem is to turn your particles to object in under render options(halo, line, ect.)Under the particle system

Comment: cycles can render hair particles.